# Java - How to store multiple JOptioPane strings in one array?

Tags: java

So, I am working on a program, called Notes counter. In the second java file, what I want is ask the user, how many notes he/she wants to add and then display all the notes in order(1.2.....)

I cannot put multiple JOoptionPane.showInpuDialogs into one array –  user2547460 31 secs ago   edit

for this line:

```
for(int i = 0; userEnterADD >i;i++){
String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your note here!");
 numberNotes= new String[userEnterADD];}
```

The abobe method should place all the user's answers from the JOoptioPane into one single array. so later I can print out all the notes the user entered for the JOOptionPane as one array,

Second file viewerN:

So I want to ask the user, "how many notes u want to add"? and I store this string as an int. and then I want to ask the user "enter your note" as many times as the int(how many notes u want to add?).

Then I want to store the user's answers in one array. string numberNotes[] array, and print them out in the infoView().. Hope, you can understand this!! Thanks

And I WANT TO PRINT OUT THE USER'S ENTERED NOTES HERE AS ONE ARRAY, how do I do that?

Thanks
    public void infoView(){

```
System.out.println("\n\tYour notes:\n");
for(int ii = 0; userEnterADD >ii;ii++){
        System.out.println(ii+1 + ". " + numberNotes[ii]);

    //end for
    }
    }



    // end of the program
}
```

Comment: Please formulate your problem and exact question in one line. What's not working?

Comment: sorry, the infoView() is not showing all the notes I asked the user, in  a String add1,

Comment: I cannot put multiple JOoptionPane.showInpuDialogs into one array

Comment: for(int i = 0; userEnterADD >i;i++){
String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your note here!");
numberNotes= new String[userEnterADD];}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the below changes

```
userEnterADD = Integer.parseInt(numbAddn);
numberNotes = new String[userEnterADD]; // Need to initialize your numberNotes array here.
...
for (int i = 0; userEnterADD > i; i++) {
    String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your note here!");
    numberNotes[i] = add1; // Add the text received from the user to your array
}
..
// System.out.println(numberNotes[2]); // Commen this line
```

What you did will keep overriding your current array with a new String array. And that SOP needs to be commented because

1. It does not serve any purpose
2. It'll give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case the user wants to enter 2 or lesser notes.

**Edit:**

After making the above changes, I got the below output by running your code

```
Heyyyy
Hi! Welcome to Notes Counter!
By Marto ©2013

        Main Menu (hint: just type the number!)

1 - Start counting
2 - View/add notes
3 - Help
4 - About
2  tttttt

You have successfully added!2       notes!

    Your notes:

1. test
2. test1
```

Comment: public void infoView(){
  
 System.out.println("\n\tYour notes:\n");
 for(int ii = 0; userEnterADD >ii;ii++){
   System.out.println(ii+1 + ". " +        numberNotes[ii]);
  
  //end for
  }
 }

Comment: it's good, but please have a look at infoView(), how do i Print this array out?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `infoView()` method. Because you're overriding your array, your `infoView()` wasn't printing properly. It'll work fine, after making the changes I told. Have a look at my answer after the edit

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at viewerN.infoAdd(viewerN.java:23)
 at NotesCounter.main(1_NotesCounter.java:53)

Comment: `numberNotes = new String[userEnterADD];` - Did you add this line, as I had told?

Comment: can you please copy the infoView? becaue I messed up it ??

Comment: Have a look at the [whole class here](http://pastie.org/8385928)(after doing the 3 changes I mentioned). This will work.

Comment: yeah, it works now, i must have done something incorrectly. you are the best programmer in the world!!! YOU are the god of programming and JAVA!!!!

Comment: It feels great to get this compliment, but that's not true(though I wish to)! Nevertheless, happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; userEnterADD >i;i++){
     String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your note here!");
     numberNotes= new String[userEnterADD];
}
```

This code will always overwrite your array.

In order to add a value to an array, use it as such:

```
for(int i = 0; userEnterADD >i;i++){
     String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your note here!");
     numberNotes[i] = add1;
}
```

Sidenote: avoid such clutter in your post the next time. 75% of your code doesn't come near being relevant, you can leave it out which will make it a lot easier for everyone. It's important that you learn how to identify a problem on your own, you'll often find the issue by making sure your question here contains all the information.

Comment: it's good, but please have a look at infoView(), how do i Print this array out?

Comment: the last method, infoView(); it does not print out the array!,

Comment: You have to be more descriptive. Are you getting any errors? Does the program quit?

Comment: this is the error! 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at viewerN.infoAdd(viewerN.java:23)
 at NotesCounter.main(1_NotesCounter.java:53)

Comment: Did you remove `System.out.println(numberNotes[2]);`?